# Skyrim no Markarth job for under new management special quests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need to get a few Markarth jobs but it won't give me any. I just get jobs for Windhelm, White Run, and Solitude but not Markarth. I just want to complete this.

Comment: I did that and it keeps giving me the other towns it's super annoying I think it's glitched

Comment: What are you playing skyrim on? xbox, playstation, or pc?

Comment: Pc please help I need to finish this quest it's making me so frustrated

Answer (score 5):

This is for the "One With the Shadows" achievement right? The jobs are chosen at random, so just quick save before you talk to them, if it's not Markath quickload and try again, that's what I did.

Comment: Is there a certain job I should pick cause I was just doing fishing jobs from delvin who's more common, vex or delvin?

Answer (score 3):

Here are your odds of getting a Markarth job:

- [Bedlam (Delvin, Dragonborn not installed)](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Bedlam_Job): 20%
- [Bedlam (Delvin, Dragonborn installed)](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Bedlam_Job): 17%
- [Numbers (Delvin)](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Numbers_Job): 15%
- [Heist (Vex)](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Heist_Job): 14.3%
- [Burglary](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Burglary_Job), [Shill](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Shill_Job) or [Sweep](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Sweep_Job) (Vex): 13.8%

The odds for Fishing jobs are a little tougher to figure out, and are highly dependent on how many citizens of each major city have fallen to Vampires, newly minted Werewolves, Dark Brotherhood members/wannabes, or *Forsworn mass jailbreaks*.  Also be aware that the *Dragonborn* DLC dilutes the target pool for Fishing too.  YMMV